# oracle not a group by expression

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table with 3 columns.

ORDER CATEGORY
NAV_PER_SHARE
Number_OUTSTANDING_SHARES

Now:

```
SELECT ORDER_CATEGORY, SUM(OUTSTANDING_SHARES) GROUP BY ORDER_CATEGORY , it runs fine
```

But:

`SELECT ORDER_CATEGORY, NAV_PER_SHARE * SUM(OUTSTANDING_SHARES) GROUP BY ORDER_CATEGORY` , it says : Not a group by expression .

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You caNnot group because `NAV_PER_SHARE` is given per result. Did you mean

```
SUM(NAV_PER_SHARE*OUTSTANDING_SHARES)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like, the solution would be to use a subquery.

```
SELECT ORDER_CATEGORY, NAV_PER_SHARE * SUM_OF_OS
FROM (SELECT ORDER_CATEGORY, SUM(OUTSTANDING_SHARES) SUM_OF_OS
      GROUP BY ORDER_CATEGORY);
```

Although, I'm not sure how your one query works without a `FROM` keyword.