# Issue with Oracle query

Tags: oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ora-00979 not a GROUP BY expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

I wrote a query like this:

```
select employeeid,presenttime,count(latitude)
from  mobilelocation
where presentdate='9-11-2011'
group by employeeid
order by presenttime desc
```

Upon executing this above query its showing the error message like this:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `presenttime` without an aggregate function in the `select` clause but not in the `group by` clause. This doesn't really make sense: how should the engine aggregate `presenttime`? If it should not, how can it aggregate `latitude`?