# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression Error, how to resolve?

Tags: oracle11g, ora-00979

```
SELECT ssn, fname, minit, lname, AVG(hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON
WHERE EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn
GROUP BY hours
ORDER BY AVG(hours) DESC
```

It shows error of 
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I wonder why its not working?
Btw, all table exist and free of any errors.
Its in Oracle AE 11g
===========UPDATE==========================
The table as requested

```
SSN FNAME   MINIT   LNAME   AVG(HOURS)
888665555   James   E   Borg    -
666884444   Ramesh  K   Narayan 40
999887777   Alicia  J   Zelaya  20
987987987   Ahmad   V   Jabbar  20
453453453   Joyce   A   English 20
123456789   John    B   Smith   20
987654321   Jennifer    S   Wallace 17.5
333445555   Franklin    T   Wong    7.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

Comment: You seem to have pasted the wrong thing into your question: you meant to post details about your tables (including `salary`), but instead you posted the result-set produced by the corrected query (which does not include `salary`).

Comment: disregard my previous request :) thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're grouping by the exact opposite of what you need. You want:

```
SELECT ssn, fname, minit, lname, AVG(hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON
WHERE EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn
GROUP BY ssn, fname, minit, lname
ORDER BY AVG(hours) DESC
```

Comment: btw, what if I want to show salary for multiple years(more than once in the DB) this query result would be outstanding....How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to `GROUP BY` the aggregated columns:

```
SELECT ssn, fname, minit, lname, AVG(hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON
WHERE EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn
GROUP BY ssn, fname, minit, lname
ORDER BY AVG(hours) DESC
```

Comment: Whatever your date column is, you would add `TO_CHAR(dateColumn, 'YYYY')` to both your column list and your `GROUP BY` list.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using an aggregation function `AVG(hours)`, you need to group the rest of the results:

```
SELECT ssn, fname, minit, lname, AVG(hours)
FROM EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON
WHERE EMPLOYEE.ssn = WORKS_ON.essn
GROUP BY ssn, fname, minit, lname
ORDER BY AVG(hours) DESC
```

Comment: What does the table with salary look like?