# Not a GROUP BY Expression & aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I was wondering why, for this query that I have right here, why I have to use the `MAX()` aggregate function for the `case` statements, and not just jump directly into the case statement:

```
select
bank_id,
tran_branch_code,
acct_sol_id,
acct_sol_name,
transaction_date,
gl_date,
transaction_id,
account_number,
max(case
        when cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) >= 1
                and cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) <= 5
                and trans_type = 'D'
            then (trans_amount)
        --else 0
    end ) Ind_Part_Tran_Dr_RBU,
max(case
        when cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) >= 1
                and cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) <= 5
                and trans_type = 'C'
            then (trans_amount)
        --else 0
    end) Ind_Part_Tran_Cr_RBU,
max(case
        when cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) = 0
                or (cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) >= 6
                and cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) <= 9)
                and trans_type = 'D'
            then (trans_amount)
        --else 0
    end)Ind_Part_Tran_Dr_FCDU,
max(case
        when cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) = 0
                or (cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) >= 6
                and cast(substr(GLSH_Code,0,1) as int) <= 9)
                and trans_type = 'C'
            then (trans_amount)
        --else 0
    end) Ind_Part_Tran_Cr_FCDU,
ccy_alias,
ccy_name,
acct_currency,
tran_currency

from
(
SELECT
    DTD.BANK_ID,
    DTD.SOL_ID Acct_Sol_ID, --Account Sol ID

dtd.br_code Tran_branch_code, -- branch code of the transacting branch
sol.sol_desc Acct_sol_name, -- name/description of SOL

DTD.TRAN_DATE Transaction_Date, --TransactionDate
DTD.GL_DATE GL_Date, --GL Date
TRIM(DTD.TRAN_ID) Transaction_ID, --Transaction ID
DTD.GL_SUB_HEAD_CODE GLSH_Code, --GLSH Code

dtd.tran_amt trans_amount,

GAM.ACCT_CRNCY_CODE Acct_Currency, --Account Currency
DTD.TRAN_CRNCY_CODE Tran_Currency, --Transaction Currency

cnc.crncy_alias_num ccy_alias,
cnc.crncy_name ccy_name,

GAM.FORACID Account_Number, --Account Number
DTD.TRAN_PARTICULAR Transaction_Particulars, --Transaction Particulars
DTD.CRNCY_CODE DTD_CCY,
--GSH.CRNCY_CODE GSH_CCY,
DTD.PART_TRAN_TYPE Transaction_Code,
--'Closing_Balance',
DTD.PSTD_USER_ID PostedBy,
CASE WHEN DTD.REVERSAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END Reversal,
TRIM(DTD.TRAN_ID) REV_ORIG_TRAN_ID,
--OTT.REF_NUM OAP_REF_NUM,
'OAP_SETTLEMENT',
'RATE_CODE',
EAB.EOD_DATE
FROM TBAADM.DTD

LEFT OUTER JOIN TBAADM.GAM ON DTD.ACID = GAM.ACID AND DTD.BANK_ID = GAM.BANK_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBAADM.EAB ON DTD.ACID = EAB.ACID AND DTD.BANK_ID = EAB.BANK_ID AND EAB.EOD_DATE = '24-MAR-2014'

left outer join tbaadm.sol on dtd.sol_id = sol.sol_id and dtd.bank_id = sol.bank_id
left outer join tbaadm.cnc on dtd.tran_crncy_code = cnc.crncy_code

WHERE  DTD.BANK_ID = 'CBC01'
AND GAM.ACCT_OWNERSHIP = 'O'
AND GAM.DEL_FLG != 'Y'
--AND DTD.TRAN_DATE = '14-APR-2014'

AND DTD.TRAN_DATE between '01-APR-2014' and '21-APR-2014'
--and foracid in ('50010112441109','50010161635051')
--and DTD.SOL_ID = '5001'
and GAM.ACCT_CRNCY_CODE = 'USD'

)

group by
    bank_id,
    tran_branch_code,
    acct_sol_id,
    acct_sol_name,
    transaction_date,
    gl_date,
    transaction_id,
    account_number,
    ccy_alias,
    ccy_name,
    Acct_Currency,
    Tran_Currency
```

Because If I would remove the `MAX()`, I'd get the "Not a GROUP BY Expression", and Toad points me to the first occurrence of the `GLSH_Code`. Based from other websites, the cure for this is really adding the `MAX()` function. **I would just like to understand why should I use that particular function, what it exactly does in the query, stuff like that**.

EDIT: inserted the rest of the code.

I know for sure what `MAX()` does, it returns the largest value in an expression. But in this case, I can't seem to figure out exactly what that largest value is that the function is attempting to return.

Comment: it seems like this is half part of your query? where is FROM clause?

Comment: @IleshPatel edited my original post, it now contains the rest of the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [ora-00979 not a GROUP BY expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Comment: @Ben i don't think so. I'm also asking as to WHY I should use such functions, and WHAT do those functions exactly do when added to the query

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` statement declares that all columns returned in the `SELECT` should be aggregated, but that you want to separate the results by those listed in the `GROUP BY`.

This means we have to use aggregate functions like `MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM, etc.` on any column that is **NOT** listed in the `GROUP BY`.

It's about telling the SQL engine what the expected results *should* be when there is more than one option.

In a simple example, we have a table with three columns:

```
PrimaryId  SubId  RowValue
1          1      1
2          1      2
3          2      4
4          2      8
```

And an SQL like the following (which is invalid):

```
 SELECT SubId, RowValue
   FROM SampleTable
  GROUP BY SubId
```

We know we want the distinct SubId's (because of the `GROUP BY`), but we don't know what RowValue should be when we aggregate the results.

```
SubId  RowValue
1      ?
2      ?
```

We have to be explicit in our query, and indicate what RowValue should be as the results can vary.

If we choose MIN(RowValue) we see:

```
SubId  RowValue
1      1
2      4
```

If we choose MAX(RowValue) we see:

```
SubId  RowValue
1      2
2      8
```

If we choose SUM(RowValue) we see:

```
SubId  RowValue
1      3
2      12
```

Without being explicit there's a high likelihood that the results will be wrong, so our SQL engine of choice protects us from ourselves by enforcing the need for aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have group by clause at the end on all the columns except for Ind_Part_Tran_Dr_RBU, Ind_Part_Tran_Cr_RBU, Ind_Part_Tran_Dr_FCDU, Ind_Part_Tran_Cr_FCDU. In this case oracle wants you to tell what to do with these columns, i.e. based on which function it has to aggregate them for every group it finds.