# SQL command fails to join tables

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to oracle sql. I am trying to execute the following Query

```
SQL> select movie.movie_title, movie.release_year, cast.movie_title, cast.release_year
from MOVIE movie, CAST_MEMBER cast 



                                                                                                                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

the query works If I don't join the actor table but I am trying to extract actor name from ACTOR table. I have looked at other problems but could not get it fixed. If someone could guide on where I am going wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where clause must come after all joins.

```
select movie.movie_title, movie.release_year, cast.movie_title, cast.release_year
from MOVIE movie, CAST_MEMBER cast 
join ACTOR actor on(actor.actor_name = cast.actor_name) 
where movie.movie_title = cast.movie_title and movie.release_year = cast.release_year 
group by cast.movie_title, cast.release_year, cast.actor_name;
```

Also, you shouldn't mix the two join notations, so it's better to write:

```
select movie.movie_title, movie.release_year, cast.movie_title, cast.release_year
from MOVIE movie
join CAST_MEMBER cast on (movie.movie_title = cast.movie_title and movie.release_year = cast.release_year)
join ACTOR actor on(actor.actor_name = cast.actor_name) 
group by cast.movie_title, cast.release_year, cast.actor_name;
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I will keep that in mind. Also ,the same question. On executing the query I get the error RROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
Does that mean I need to include COUNT, SUM etc somewhere in the query?
thank you for the response and help.

Comment: @Mani take a look here for an explanation of that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1520641/2947592

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't mix your join syntaxes:

```
select distinct 
movie.movie_title, movie.release_year, 
cast.movie_title, cast.release_year
from MOVIE movie
inner join CAST_MEMBER cast 
on movie.movie_title = cast.movie_title and movie.release_year = cast.release_year
inner join ACTOR actor 
on actor.actor_name = cast.actor_name;
```

I have also removed the group by and replaced it with distinct

Comment: Since when is distinct better than group by? Did I miss the memo?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thank you for the quick reply, just had a follow up question, the query produces the following error, 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.
Is that because group by expression works with count , sum etc? Do i need to include atleast one of them? I am trying to print the MOVIE_TITLE, RELEASE_YEAR and ACTOR_NAME from this query.

Comment: @popvitsj: personally I only use group by when the intention is to aggregate something else. If the intention is to remove duplicates I use distinct. That's my personal preference. There is no memo. Anyway, Mani, Did this error appear in your original query? It would have been nice to know that. What is your intention of using group by? Have you tried the query without using group by at all?