# Group by function column

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing a query like this...

`select to_char(e_date, 'MON/YYYY') as Month , location_code, count(employee_number) from`...

Now I want to group by Month and Location_code. so how to use `to_char(e_date, 'MON/YYYY') as Month` in group by clause?

**EDIT:**

```
select to_char(vheda.e_date, 'MON/YYYY') as Months , hla.location_code, count(vheda.employee_number) emp_count from 
virtu.virt_hr_emp_daily_attendance vheda 
inner join per_all_people_f papf on vheda.party_id = papf.party_id
inner join per_all_assignments_f paaf on papf.person_id = paaf.person_id 
inner join hr_locations_all hla on paaf.location_id = hla.location_id 
where (trunc(sysdate) between PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 
--and (vheda.e_in_time is not null)
and vheda.e_duration <> 0
and (trunc(sysdate) between PAAF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and PAAF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 
and vheda.e_date between '1-aug-2014' and '31-oct-2014'
group by hla.location_code, vheda.e_date
order by vheda.e_date
```

**OUT PUT WHEN USE GROUP BY CLAUSE `group by to_char(vheda.e_date, 'MON/YYYY'), hla.location_code`:**

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 58 Column: 37

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(e_date, 'MON/YYYY') as Month , location_code, count(employee_number) 
from ...
group by to_char(e_date, 'MON/YYYY'), location_code
```

Comment: @Chathuranga Then you have something else in the SELECT list. Give more details please

Comment: @Chathuranga Can you post the whole query? Or at least SELECT and GROUP BY

Comment: so I need to remove vheda.e_date and add new to_char column

Comment: @Chathuranga Yes, you need group by hla.location_code, to_char(vheda.e_date, 'MON/YYYY')

Comment: but it gives an error :( i,m usng oracle sql developer tool

Comment: pls see the last section of the post

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group by` To_char(vheda.e_date, 'MON/YYYY') and hla.location_code.

```
SELECT To_char(vheda.e_date, 'MON/YYYY') AS Months, 
       hla.location_code, 
       Count(vheda.employee_number)      emp_count 
FROM   virtu.virt_hr_emp_daily_attendance vheda 
       inner join per_all_people_f papf 
               ON vheda.party_id = papf.party_id 
       inner join per_all_assignments_f paaf 
               ON papf.person_id = paaf.person_id 
       inner join hr_locations_all hla 
               ON paaf.location_id = hla.location_id 
WHERE  ( Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.effective_start_date AND 
                                PAPF.effective_end_date ) 
       --and (vheda.e_in_time is not null) 
       AND vheda.e_duration <> 0 
       AND ( Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAF.effective_start_date AND 
                                    PAAF.effective_end_date ) 
       AND vheda.e_date BETWEEN '1-aug-2014' AND '31-oct-2014' 
GROUP  BY To_char(vheda.e_date, 'MON/YYYY'),
          hla.location_code
ORDER  BY vheda.e_date
```

For example, let's see the same with `EMP` table,

```
SQL> SELECT To_char(hiredate, 'MON/YYYY') AS Months,
  2         deptno,
  3         Count(empno)                  emp_count
  4  FROM   emp
  5  GROUP  BY To_char(hiredate, 'MON/YYYY'),
  6            deptno
  7  /

MONTHS       DEPTNO  EMP_COUNT
-------- ---------- ----------
DEC/1980         20          1
JUN/1981         10          1
NOV/1981         10          1
MAY/1987         20          1
FEB/1981         30          2
MAY/1981         30          1
DEC/1981         30          1
JAN/1982         10          1
SEP/1981         30          2
DEC/1981         20          1
APR/1981         20          1
APR/1987         20          1

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: but this gives an error  "not a GROUP BY expression" when I use To_char... in group by clause??

Comment: Show your session results from SQL*Plus, like I did. Copy paste and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e_date)||'/'|| EXTRACT(Year FROM e_date) as months , location_code,    count(employee_number) 
FROM ...
group by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e_date)||'/'|| EXTRACT(Year FROM e_date), location_code
```

You can also use EXTRACT function in GROUP BY clause..
i hope it helps..