# Oracle display customer who purchased most cars

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm currently trying to answer the following question:

Display the name of the customer who has purchased the most cars from Archie’s Luxury Motors.

Tables I'm working with:

**Customer**

```
(custID, name, DOB, streetAddress, suburb, postcode,
gender, phoneNo, email, type)
```

**SalesTransaction**

```
(VIN, custID, agentID, dateOfSale, agreedPrice)
```

I have tried the following query:

```
select customer.name
from customer, salestransaction
where customer.custid = salestransaction.custid
group by (salestransaction.custid)
having count(salestransaction.custid) = max(salestransaction.custid);
```

I receive the following error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post some sample data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this should work:

```
select * from (
select customer.name
from customer, salestransaction
where customer.custID = salestransaction.custID
group by (salestransaction.custID), customer.name
order by count(*) desc
) where rownum=1
```

Comment: This is perfect mate, but because I only need to show the name, not the count aswell, what can I exclude from the query?

Comment: You can exclude count(*) that is after customer.name, I will edit the answer if you want to remove the count as well

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way utilizes a RANK:

```
select customer.name, st.cnt
from customer
join
 ( 
   select 
      custid,
      count(*) as cnt,
      rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
   from salestransaction
   group by custid
 ) st
on customer.custid = st.custid 
where st.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
select customer.name, count(*)
from customer, salestransaction
where customer.custid = salestransaction.custid
group by (salestransaction.custid)
order by count(*) desc
) where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Join them using joins rather than in the where clause, also put the

```
SELECT c.name, MAX(s.custid) FROM (
SELECT c.name, Count(s.custid)
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN salestransaction s ON c.custid = s.custid
GROUP BY c.name);
```

Comment: This code doesn't output just a single name with the most purchased cars though. It will output a list of all customer names with a count of how many cars purchased. 

Also, I tried a couple queries with joins instead of joining them in the where clause but I still don't get the answer I need.