# Oracle, inner join with group by clause

Tags: oracle

I have two oracle tables :

> USERS : ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, ROLE
>
> ARCHIVE_POSESSION : ID, USERID, ARCHIVEID

What I'm trying to do is obtain a query that returns me the following result set :

> Username, Role, Number Of Archives

So far so good, but I can't wrap my head around the query, I'm still a beginner. So far this is where I got:

```
SELECT users.ID, USERNAME, ROLE, count(archive_posession.USERID) 
from users inner join 
archive_posession on 
users.id = archive_posession.USERID 
group by 
archive_posession.USERID ;
```

But it gives me this error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Any tips? I'm sure group by is supposed to work for aggregate functions, but in this case I'm stoked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fields that you select are either be declared in group by or you should use an [aggregate function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/group-by-functions.html). 
For example

```
SELECT archive_posession, Max(USERID USERNAME), Max(ROLE), count(archive_posession.USERID) 
FROM users INNER JOIN
archive_posession ON 
users.id = archive_posession.USERID 
GROUP BY 
archive_posession.USERID ;
```

should do the trick.

The reason why that resolves this issue is because Group By returns a single row. So you should find a way to gather all selected fields that are not in group by in a single row only

Comment: Thanks for the effort but he got it first. Your post was informative so I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to do something like

```
SELECT u.USERNAME, u.ROLE, COUNT(a.USERID)
  FROM USERS u
  INNER JOIN ARCHIVE_POSESSION a
    ON a.USERID = u.ID
  GROUP BY u.USERNAME, u.ROLE;
```

All columns in the SELECT list of a GROUP BY query must either be members of the GROUP BY list, or must be an aggregate function such as COUNT. In your query USERNAME and ROLE were not members of the GROUP BY list, and thus the query you saw was produced.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! But there's a typo in your query, it's u.ID.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Corrected.

Comment: You got it wrong again. lol. ON a.USERID = u.ID . Anyway I'll vote your answer as correct.

Comment: To be fair, @istovatis posted his answer before mine.