# ORA-00979, but I have elements in my SELECT in my GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3,
       field4,
       field5,
       field6,
       field7,
       field8,
       field9,
       count(field9)
  FROM REPORT_TABLE
       LEFT JOIN
       DATAMINE
         USING (REPORT_ID)
 WHERE field1 LIKE 'MatchingText%'
   AND TS_START between to_date('2015-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2015-06-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 0.99999999
GROUP BY field9,
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5,
         6,
         7,
         8,
         9;
```

When I reun it, I get

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression) question, explaining that I need to include all fields in the `select` in the `group by`. I've done that by having the column numbers.

How can I adjust this query so that I don't get the `00979` error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've done that by having the column numbers.

That works in databases like PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT abc, xyz
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1, 2 -- referencing abc and xyz by column number
```

But not in Oracle. In Oracle, you cannot reference to your `SELECT` clause from your `GROUP BY` clause, but you have to repeat the full column expressions again

```
SELECT abc, xyz
FROM ...
GROUP BY abc, xyz
```

... or in your case:

```
[...]
GROUP BY 
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    field4,
    field5,
    field6,
    field7,
    field8,
    field9;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just be able to group by non counting or aggregate fields and get not get an error. You may also need to add a naming convention since you are counting field9 and also counting by it

```
SELECT 
field1,
field2,
field3,
field4,
field5,
field6,
field7,
field8,
field9,
count(field9)  AS "Field9_Count"
FROM REPORT_TABLE
LEFT JOIN DATAMINE
    USING (REPORT_ID)
WHERE  ( field1 LIKE 'MatchingText%') AND TS_START between to_date('2015-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2015-06-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')+0.99999999 
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9
```