# Group By expression not working in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL. Could anyone help me to figure out why the "Group By" Expression isn't working in this sql query? I get this error

```
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

The code I am using is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CUSTOMER_LINE_ITEM AS
SELECT CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.loginName,CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.FirstName,
CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.LastName,CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.orderCartID,(lineItems.orderPrice*lineItems.qtyOrdered) AS TOTAL_ORDER
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO
INNER JOIN lineItems
ON CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.orderCartID = lineItems.orderCartID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.loginName,CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.FirstName,
CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.LastName,CUSTOMER_ORDER_CART_INFO.orderCartID
ORDER BY orderCartID;
```

Without the Group By expression I generate this view. I think the group by expression should just remove the duplicates and just give me the results with different order cart ID. Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?
[VIEW of CUSTOMER_LINE_ITEM without 'group by'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql0e5.png)

Comment: I suggest to add TOTAL_ORDER to the GROUP BY expression, as I think this error indicates that not all columns in select list are also in group by expression - but have not tried out.

Comment: Have you tried [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+not+a+group+by)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Comment: @Aleksej. It wasn't a duplicate question. I searched for Group by expression in stack overflow , but I couldn't find my answer. The solution is also different from your suggested duplicate question.

Comment: The answer you accepted says " all columns being selected to be in group by clause"; the accepted answer of the question I linked says "You must put all columns of the SELECT in the GROUP BY", which is exactly the same thing: this is a duplicate question

Comment: @Aleksej Well, there was two parts to that answer... even if I select all the columns of my table, it wouldn't still work as I didn't have a aggregate function for the part of the columns which were not originally part of the group and group by would still give me an error message. I still don't think it's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with group by clause. Remember simple rule of thumb, all columns being selected to be in group by clause, or the columns to be selected which are not part of group by clause are to be selected as some aggregate function, like, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG, etc.

Try the following query, which would run without issue. But I can't say its logical correctness which you need to figure out on your requirement basis.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW customer_line_item AS
    SELECT cac.loginName,
           cac.FirstName,
           cac.LastName,
           cac.orderCartID,
           (SUM(li.orderPrice) * SUM(li.qtyOrdered)) AS TOTAL_ORDER
      FROM customer_order_cart_info cac
     INNER JOIN lineItems li
        ON cac.orderCartID = li.orderCartID
     GROUP BY cac.loginName,
              cac.FirstName,
              cac.LastName,
              cac.orderCartID
     ORDER BY cac.orderCartID;
```

Now thing to note here is, li.orderPrice and li.qtyOrdered were being selected, but were neither in group by nor in a aggregate function.
The use of group by is that, the columns in group by clause are used to logically group your data. Here your data is grouped by loginName, firstname, lastname, ordercartid. But there is a probability that multiple orderprice and qty exist for each group, and SQL is not able to justify the grouping logic then. Per your query one requirement that I could think of was, you want find the total value of order for a customer in his cart. Hence, you are multiplying orderPrice with qtyOrdered. To achieve this, you need to multiply orderPrice and orderqty of each lineItem. Hence, what you need is a sum of (orderPrice*orderQty) group by lineItem(lineItemID/lineItemNo maybe, just a guess). For this one, give me some time, let me devise an example and I will edit my answer with that. Till then you try something like above.

Comment: I guess too late. Anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error message is that you don't aggregate `(lineItems.orderPrice*lineItems.qtyOrdered)`.

The Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) tells us

> SelectItems in the SelectExpression with a GROUP BY clause must
>   contain only aggregates or grouping columns.

That means you should aggregate TOTAL_ORDER by using e.g.

```
sum(lineItems.orderPrice*lineItems.qtyOrdered)
```

or whatever the requirement is.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked! I understand what went wrong.