# Can't Grouping Data in Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I have an Oracle query that currently display all of my data

```
$qu = 'SELECT * FROM baan.tcbpur012777 WHERE T$RQNO LIKE :bagian GROUP BY tcbpur012777.T$RQNO ORDER BY T$RQNO OFFSET '.$start.' ROWS FETCH NEXT '.$perPage.' ROWS ONLY';
$r = oci_parse($conn, $qu);
oci_bind_by_name($r,':bagian',$bag);
oci_execute($r);
$n = oci_fetch_all($r, $q);
```

What i wanna do is group the duplicated data into one,But Every time i use group by syntax, warning will appear and make my syntax invalid.

```
Warning: oci_fetch_all(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in
```

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with my syntax??
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"What i wanna do is group the duplicated data into one"* -- `GROUP BY` does not do this. It doesn't remove duplicate rows, it doesn't even returns rows from the table (and `SELECT * ... GROUP BY` is invalid SQL). `GROUP BY` fetches rows from the table, put them in groups by the `GROUP BY` expressions then it **computes** the `SELECT` expressions using the values from each group. It **generates** one record from each group.

Comment: okay, thanks for the explanation, do you have any suggestion for my problem?? Usually in MySQL, i use GROUP BY to do that

Comment: Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to accept invalid `GROUP BY` queries but it reserved its right to [return indeterminate values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for the `SELECT` expressions that are not calls of [aggregate (`GROUP BY`) functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and are not also present in the `GROUP BY` clause (all the columns of `tcbpur012777` except for `T$RQNO` in your query). It doesn't accept invalid `GROUP BY` queries since 5.7.5. Oracle also doesn't accept them.

Comment: If you want to ignore duplicates you can try to `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ... FROM baan.tcbpur012777...`. You have to put into the query each column you need (I guess two rows you consider duplicates are not equal on all columns, they have different values for the `PK`). You don't need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks it work with SELECT DISTINCT :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY column_name
```

You need to either [include all the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520641/1509264) or, for each column not in the `GROUP BY` clause you need to use an [aggregation function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) to aggregate it over the group. Assuming your table has more than one column then `SELECT *` will get all those columns but `GROUP BY column_name` is only grouping by one of the columns and the other columns are not part of an aggregation so it will throw an `ORA-00979 not a group by expression` exception.

Something like:

```
SELECT   T$RQNO,
         MAX( Col1 ) AS MaxCol1,
         MIN( Col2 ) AS MinCol2,
         LISTAGG( Col3, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Col4 ) AS ListOfCol3
FROM     baan.tcbpur012777
WHERE    T$RQNO LIKE :bagian
GROUP BY T$RQNO
ORDER BY T$RQNO
OFFSET     '.$start.' ROWS
FETCH NEXT '.$perPage.' ROWS ONLY
```