# sqlplus query help needed, getting error while executing

Tags: sql, oracle

What am I doing wrong below?

```
select D_OPERATION_DATE, count(*)
from 
(select to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON') D_OPERATION_DATE, SUM (N_OPERATION_FEE) from SBM_BILLING_RESULT where c_operation_type='Commit' and C_RESULT_STATUS='SUCCESS')
group by D_OPERATION_DATE;
```

> Error:
>   ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
>   00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 13 Column: 17

Any leads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'sum()' in your inner statement with individual column name 'to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON')'.
In this case you need to that 'GROUP BY to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON')' to the end of inner statement.

```
    select D_OPERATION_DATE, count(*) 
from (
    select to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON') D_OPERATION_DATE, SUM (N_OPERATION_FEE) 
    from SBM_BILLING_RESULT 
    where c_operation_type='Commit' and C_RESULT_STATUS='SUCCESS' 
    GROUP BY to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON')
    )
group by D_OPERATION_DATE;
```

Comment: Hello,
But it is still not returning sum of column (N_OPERATION_FEE)
It is returning as 
Nov 1
Dec 1

I want like 
Nov 35
Dec 28

Comment: This query is also not working ..

select D_OPERATION_DATE, sum(N_OPERATION_FEE) 
from (
    select to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON') D_OPERATION_DATE 
    from SBM_BILLING_RESULT 
    where c_operation_type='Commit' and C_RESULT_STATUS='SUCCESS' 
    GROUP BY to_char(D_OPERATION_DATE, 'MON')
    )
group by D_OPERATION_DATE;

Comment: when you say it's not working, do you mean it ends up with error or you just don't get the result you want?

Comment: I am not getting what I want ..
but finally achieved it :)
Thanks a lot my friend!