# Writing a statement to create a report using group by but not group by expression error obtained

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Question: 
A report listing all courses and their total number of attendances which have more than 5 attendances in each course by using aggregate function with GROUP BY and “HAVING” condition

Statement:

```
SELECT SUM(NO_OF_ATTENDANCES), COURSE_ID, EXERCISE_TYPE, COURSE_LOC
FROM I_COURSE
GROUP BY COURSE_LOC
HAVING SUM(NO_OF_ATTENDANCES) > 5;
```

Please help me and tell me what is wrong and why the error is obtained.

Table name is I_COURSE

Attributes are: COURSE_ID, EXERCISE_TYPE, COURSE_LOC, NO_OF_ATTENDANCES

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle DB ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Comment: All the non-aggregate columns in the select list probably need to be listed in the GROUP BY clause — at least, the retrograde versions of SQL I'm used to working with require that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Actually, no. Did you read the question in detail? The non-aggregate columns in the select list, in this case, should be removed from the select list - not added to GROUP BY, which would result in an entirely different result.

Comment: @mathguy: I didn't read the question in detail, but it remains true that in classic SQL systems, the non-aggregate columns in the select-list should match the columns listed in the GROUP BY.  You can reconcile the difference by adding columns to the GROUP BY (which is certainly what I envisaged, but there are issues with what the query is really supposed to find), _OR_ by removing columns from the select-list.  Both techniques "work" (as in, produce executable SQL). I've not spent time studying the data and the desired results — neither of which is on display. There are reasons for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to group by `COURSE_ID` as :

```
SELECT SUM(NO_OF_ATTENDANCES), COURSE_ID
FROM I_COURSE
GROUP BY COURSE_ID
HAVING SUM(NO_OF_ATTENDANCES) > 5;
```

*Firstly COURSE_ID column is enough for your desired result, and it's not possible to include [non-aggregated] columns in the SELECT list those are not in the GROUP BY list.*