# Hibernate namedquery throws ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

I have a problem about getting the result from namedquery based on hibernate.

Here are the namedqueries here.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "DetailOrder.bestSelling", 
    query = "SELECT do.book FROM DetailOrder do GROUP BY do.book.id "
                    + "ORDER BY SUM(do.quantity) DESC")


@NamedQuery(name = "Review.mostFavoredBooks",
    query = "SELECT r.bookReview, COUNT(r.bookReview.id) AS ReviewCount, AVG(r.rating) as AvgRating FROM Review r "
                        + "GROUP BY r.bookReview.id HAVING AVG(r.rating) >= 4.0 "
                        + "ORDER BY ReviewCount DESC, AvgRating DESC")
```

Values and alias are correct.

Here are the functions related with namedqueries.

```
public List<Book> listMostFavoredBooks() {
        List<Book> mostFavoredBooks = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Object[]> result = super.findByNameQueryObjects("Review.mostFavoredBooks", 0, 4);

        System.out.println("listMostFavoredBooks | result size :" + result.size());

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            for (Object[] elements : result) {
                Book book = (Book) elements[0];
                mostFavoredBooks.add(book);
            }
        } 

        return mostFavoredBooks;
    }

public List<Book> listBestSellingBooks() {
        return super.findByNameQuery("DetailOrder.bestSelling", 0, 4);
}
```

When I get the result from namedqueries defined as above, there is the same issue for all them.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer How can I change the query? Is it possible to write it if you don't mind.

Comment: you can write two independent queries
one for count and another for avg.
You should read the answer in above link.
"You must put all columns of the SELECT in the GROUP BY or use functions on them which compress the results to a **single** value (like MIN, MAX or SUM)."

Comment: @RDK I edit the post.

Comment: Which query is in error? Some explanation about what does the 2nd one?

Comment: @pdem The 2nd one is the same as  1st one named for not showing  a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer

```
SELECT do.book_ıd,SUM(do.quantity) FROM detaılorder do LEFT JOIN book b on do.book_ıd = b.book_ıd
GROUP BY do.book_ıd
ORDER BY SUM(do.quantity) DESC;

SELECT r.book_ıd,COUNT(r.book_ıd) AS ReviewCount,AVG(r.rating) as AvgRating FROM revıew r LEFT JOIN book b on r.book_ıd = b.book_ıd
GROUP BY r.book_ıd HAVING AVG(r.rating) >= 4.0
ORDER BY ReviewCount DESC, AvgRating DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this select:

```
SELECT do.book 
FROM DetailOrder do 
GROUP BY do.book.id 
ORDER BY SUM(do.quantity) DESC
```

is Oracle sql is incorrect. The select and the group by expression must match.

I think that the "query" part of this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "DetailOrder.bestSelling", 
query = "SELECT do.book FROM DetailOrder do GROUP BY do.book.id "
                + "ORDER BY SUM(do.quantity) DESC")
```

Is in fact a real sql sentence, not an hibernate one.

Comment: I also write @NamedQuery(name = "DetailOrder.bestSelling", 
query = "SELECT do.book FROM DetailOrder do GROUP BY do.book "
                + "ORDER BY SUM(do.quantity) DESC")  but nothing changed.

Comment: This is not correct, the correct query would be: "select do.book. sum(do.quantity) from DetailOrder do GROUP BY do.book order by 2 desc". This should work directly in oracle