# To calculate department wise percentage of employees

Tags: sql, oracle

table DEPT looks like this.

| dname | NO_of_emp |
| --- | --- |
| Hr | 10 |
| Finance | 30 |
| Analyst | 50 |

Need output like below.

| dname | NO_of_emp | per_of_emp_dept_wise |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hr | 10 | 11.11 |
| Finance | 30 | 33.33 |
| Analyst | 50 | 55.55 |

to get 'per_of_emp_dept_wise' column  logic is : ((NO_of_emp /total NO_of_emp) *100)

How to achieve this.

tried using rollup:

```
SELECT
    dname,
    SUM(no_of_emp),
    ( ( no_of_emp ) / SUM(no_of_emp) * 100 )
FROM
    dept
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(deptno);--> gives error  ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.
```

but not able to include rollup data into SELECT section to calculate new('per_of_emp_dept_wise') column.

Can any one suggest solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Rajini

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Comment: You can use markdown for codes and table https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with aux (dname, no_of_emp) as(
    select 'HR', 10 from dual union all
    select 'FINANCE', 30 from dual union all
    select 'ANALYST', 50 from dual)
SELECT
    a.*,
    round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(no_of_emp) OVER() * 100, 2) per_of_emp_dept_wise,
    round(a.no_of_emp / SUM(no_of_emp) OVER() * 100, 2) per_of_emp_dept_wise_2
FROM
    aux a
```

Comment: yes. got a desired result. Thanks A LOT. can we do it without RATIO_TO_REPORT analytical function?

Comment: @Rajini you're welcome. Updated without ratio_to_report.