# Selecting a column from a table and the Count() of a column in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Consider the following tables:

```
   TABLE PAPER // it contains IDs of scientific papers and IDs of the scientists who wrote them
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ PaperID   ║ ScientistID ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 10        ║ 1           ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 11        ║ 1           ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 12        ║ 2           ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 13        ║ 3           ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝


   TABLE SCIENTISTS // it contains IDs of scientists and their names
╔═════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ScientistID ║ ScientistName  ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 1           ║ Tikola Nesla   ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 2           ║ Carie Murie    ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 3           ║ Nsaac Iewton   ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I'm looking for a SELECT query that prints names of scientists and how many times they released a scientific paper, the desired result should be this:

```
CountOfPapersPerScientist     ScientistName
-------------------------     -------------
                        2      Tikola Nesla 
                        1       Carie Murie
                        1      Nsaac Iewton
```

I was able to print just the count of papers per scientist using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(PaperID) FROM PAPER GROUP BY ScientistID;
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(PaperID), ScientistName FROM PAPER, SCIENTISTS WHERE SCIENTISTS.ScientistID=PAPER.ScientistID GROUP BY PAPER.ScientistID;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

What is a "GROUP BY expression" and why my query isn't one? What alternative query could I use?

Comment: is it oracle or mysql? only tag that is relevant

Comment: you should to left join scientists table

Comment: See: [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520608/1422451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you need , simple group by and join :

```
select s.ScientistName, count(p.paperId) CountOfPapersPerScientist
from paper p
join SCIENTISTS s on p.ScientistID = s.ScientistID
group by s.ScientistName
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you so much! can you please explain why it didn't work before?

Comment: @Chainsburg you were grouping by ScientistID while , so you can only select ScientistID column and aggregates but you were selecting ScientistName, so yo have to group by ScientistName .also always use explicit joins

Comment: @Chainsburg This may not give the expected result if you have two different scientists with the identical names.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a "GROUP BY expression" and why my query isn't one?

When you use a `GROUP BY` clause then all the columns in the `SELECT` clause need to be either:

- Listed in the `GROUP BY` clause; or
- Wrapped in an aggregation function (such as `SUM`, `COUNT`, `LISTAGG`, etc.).

You have `GROUP BY s.ScientistId` and use `ScientistName` in the `SELECT` clause which is neither listed in the `GROUP BY` clause nor wrapped in an aggregation function.

---

What you need is:

```sql
SELECT MAX(s.ScientistName) AS ScientistName,
       count(p.paperId) CountOfPapersPerScientist
FROM   paper p
       INNER JOIN scientists s
       On p.ScientistID = s.ScientistID
GROUP BY
       s.ScientistId;
```

or

```sql
SELECT s.ScientistName,
       count(p.paperId) CountOfPapersPerScientist
FROM   paper p
       INNER JOIN scientists s
       On p.ScientistID = s.ScientistID
GROUP BY
       s.ScientistId, s.ScientistName;
```

As both of these will group by the primary key of the identifier for the scientist.

If you only group by the name then you will aggregate the numbers of papers of two different scientists who happen to have the same name together and this is probably not what you want and you need to make sure that you are grouping by something unique to each scientist (and their name may not be unique).

---

For example, if you have the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Scientists (ScientistId PRIMARY KEY, ScientistName, DateOfBirth) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', DATE '1990-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Alice', DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE paper (PaperID, ScientistID) AS
SELECT 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 4 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE paper ADD CONSTRAINT paper__scientistid__fk FOREIGN KEY (ScientistId) REFERENCES Scientists (ScientistId);
```

Then the queries above both output:

> | SCIENTISTNAME | COUNTOFPAPERSPERSCIENTIST |
> | --- | --- |
> | Alice | 2 |
> | Beryl | 1 |
> | Carol | 1 |
> | Alice | 1 |

And there is one row for each unique scientist (even though two have identical names).

However, naively grouping only on `ScientistName` would output:

> | SCIENTISTNAME | COUNTOFPAPERSPERSCIENTIST |
> | --- | --- |
> | Alice | 3 |
> | Beryl | 1 |
> | Carol | 1 |

Which is wrong as there are two different scientists named `Alice`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=21a360fabd05988d9ca419899c596be0)*