# NOT GROUP By issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to make a sum in this formula but I have one issue, not group by expression ?

WHo is the problem ?

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM( FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF + 
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA +
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND +
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ
              ) /
         3600 * 10
       )
FROM FACT_WLT_AGENT,
     dim_reorganization reorg
WHERE FACT_WLT_AGENT.reorg_id = reorg.reorg_id
  AND is_last_master_reorg    = 'Y'
HAVING FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF +
       FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA + 
       FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND +
       FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ /
       3600 > 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the problem, I'll use modified Scott's sample schema.

```
SQL> select sal, comm from emp where deptno = 10;

       SAL       COMM
---------- ----------
      2450        245
      5000        500
      1300        130

SQL>
```

This is your current code (which doesn't work):

```
SQL> select sum(sal + comm) result
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10
  4  having sal + comm > 0;
having sal + comm > 0
       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression


SQL>
```

Now, you can "fix" it by adding a `group by` clause, but I don't think that this is what you want:

```
SQL> select sum(sal + comm) result
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10
  4  group by sal + comm
  5  having sal + comm > 0;

    RESULT
----------
      5500
      2695
      1430

SQL>
```

I believe that you actually want this - use aggregation in `having` clause:

```
SQL> select sum(sal + comm) result
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 10
  4  having sum(sal + comm) > 0;

    RESULT
----------
      9625

SQL>
```

---

Or, in your case:

```
SELECT ROUND( SUM( FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF + 
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA +
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND +
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ
              ) /
         3600 * 10
       )
FROM FACT_WLT_AGENT,
     dim_reorganization reorg
WHERE FACT_WLT_AGENT.reorg_id = reorg.reorg_id
  AND is_last_master_reorg    = 'Y'
HAVING sum(FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF +
           FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA + 
           FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND +
           FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`group by` is required of any field named in either `sum` or `having`. In this case you have both, so you need something like this;

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF + FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA + FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND + FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ)/ 3600 * 10 )

FROM FACT_WLT_AGENT, dim_reorganization reorg 
WHERE FACT_WLT_AGENT.reorg_id = reorg.reorg_id 
AND is_last_master_reorg = 'Y' 
group by FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF, FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA, FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND, FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ
HAVING FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF + FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA + FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND + FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ / 3600 > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`select` statements are [conceptually] evaluated sequentially like this, though one should note that internally, for performance reasons, things are unlikely to actually work this way:

- Form the cartesian product of all tables in the `from` clause.
- Apply the join criteria (if any), removing any rows that don't match.
- Apply the criteria in the `where` clause (if any), again removing any rows that don't match.
- If a `group by` clause is present,

  - Collapse/Summarize each group to a single row, computing the values of all aggregate function, and removing all columns/expressions that are not in the `group by` list or are an aggregate function.
  - Apply the criteria in the `having` clause (if any) to filter the result set.

7. Order the result set by the columns/expressions specified in the `order by` clause.

You cannot specify a `having` clause without first having specified a `group by` clause. Lacking the `group by` clause, your `having` clause is syntactically invalid.

Comment: The GROUP BY is actually not required to have a HAVING clause. See example in @Littlefoot's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply use a *derived table*, to save some typing and but also to reduce the risk of errors when repeating the same columns over and over again:

```
SELECT the_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT ROUND( SUM( FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_FNGF + 
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_ENA +
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_EEIND +
                   FACT_WLT_AGENT.WLT_LHV_PO_PAQ
              ) / 3600 * 10) as the_sum
    FROM FACT_WLT_AGENT
    JOIN dim_reorganization reorg
      ON FACT_WLT_AGENT.reorg_id = reorg.reorg_id
    WHERE is_last_master_reorg    = 'Y
) dt
WHERE the_sum > 0;
```

Note the explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!